# asp EmptyDataTemplate not always working

Tags: asp.net, listview, dropdown, emptydatatemplate

I have a listview which bind data on selected country value dropdownlist from sharepoint diffrent lists by country, sometimes the list is empty so I add :

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>
<div>No records found. </div>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

Scenario:

1. from Dropdownlist(countries list), I choose an empty list (country 1), it displays "No records found"
2. from Dropdownlist, I choose a non empty list (country 2), it displays the records
3. but from Dropdownlist, when I want to get back to (country 1) which is empty, it still displays data from (country 2)
4. from Dropdownlist, When I choose a non empty (country 3), it displays the records

So I don't know why in step 3 when I turn back to (country 1) or even if I choose another empty country list it still display the records from non empty list.
Help Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rebind the gridview to an empty data source when the country is empty.

```
if(countryHasNoRecords)
{
   gvMyGridView.DataSource = null;
   gvMyGridView.DataBind();
}
```